# NHibernate Saving an object

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I have a profile object that links to a details object (1 to 1). So on my profile object I have the detail object as a property and I am trying to map the details object using a HasOne mapping. When the profile is being saved, it is creating a profile entry in the db and a detail entry; however, the profileId on the details object is Guid.Empty. Its not using the Id its generating on the profile to save the details:

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance

Below are my maps:

```
public ProfileMap() : base(ESchema.Usr, ETable.Profile)
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            Map(x => x.MembershipId);
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);
            Map(x => x.Gender).CustomType<EGender>();
            Map(x => x.BirthDate);
            Map(x => x.IsActive);

            HasOne(x => x.Details).PropertyRef(x => x.ProfileId).Cascade.All();
            //References(x => x.ProfileImage).Column("ProfileId");
        }

public DetailMap() : base(ESchema.Usr, ETable.Detail)
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            Map(x => x.ProfileId);
            Map(x => x.Height);
            Map(x => x.Weight);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The section on one-to-one in the NHibernate reference (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) seems to suggest (towards the end) that Detail.ProfileId should really be e.g. OwningProfile (typed as Profile) and mapped (in fluent NH) using References().